# Feynman rules for gauge bosons and Goldstone bosons

Tags: resource-recommendations, feynman-diagrams, higgs, electroweak, propagator

Does anyone know where I can find:

- gauge boson propagators (in an unfixed gauge) for the unphysical
  Electroweak gauge bosons $A^1_\mu$, $A^2_\mu$, $A^3_\mu$ and
  $A^4_\mu$ whose combinations give the physical $W^+_\mu$, $W^-_\mu$,
  $A_\mu$ and $Z_\mu$? (With the form of the Higgs doublet clearly
  stated).
- vertex couplings for $A^1_\mu$, $A^2_\mu$, $A^3_\mu$ and $A^4_\mu$
  with the Higgs
- propagator for the Higgs boson field
- propagator of the Golstone boson arising from the Higgs mechanism in
  EW
- couplings of the Goldstone boson to the fields

I want to compute radiative corrections to some of the propagators of $A^1_\mu$, $A^2_\mu$, $A^3_\mu$ and $A^4_\mu$ due to the higgs boson, but I would like to do that (analytically) without deriving all feynman rules by myself.

Comment: The propagators for all vector bosons look pretty much the sense, and those of the scalar bosons also all look the same, it doesn't matter where these bosons come from. I don't understand the question.

Comment: Could you tell me where I can find them? No doubt they may look similar, I just don't know them and don't know where to find them, specially for the unphysical fields.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested, I found a good document with all Feynman rules and different notations:

http://arxiv.org/abs/1209.6213